# Is it possible to have a single trial per device?

Tags: iphone, android, security

Is it possible to provide a service in which one free trial is given to each device without the possibility of an individual being able to get multiple free trials on a single device.  If its impossible,  do you know of a way of making it difficult to obtain multiple free trials.

Comment: Beware that the android ID is apparently not unique - allegedly there's a model/firmware version out there where all devices have the same id.

Comment: I do that :) Also Windows Mobile. Note that unique device ID is very hard to come by on Android.

Comment: The device ID obtained through Settings.Secure can change on a factory reset of the device. The device ID obtained through TelephonyManager may not exist (if, say, the device is not a telephone).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can generate the license key based on the device's unique ID, the request date, and your own private key to create a license that is only valid up to certain date.

You application will verify that the license key is valid by decoding the license key with your public key, and comparing its expiration date and device ID. People can't forge a bogus request, since the license key is only valid for the prescribed date and a given device ID.

(hint: read about public-key cryptography)

However, it's not totally foolproof. A really determined attacker can root his device, and install a custom firmware which allows him to control identifier returned by "getDeviceId()". This isn't something that most people would be willing to do, most people would rather find an alternative free app or just buy the app rather than going through that route. Against crackers with that sort of determination and skills, there is not much you can do about.

Alternative avenue of attack would be to replace the public key you ship with the application with the attacker's private/public key combination, and he can potentially write a key generator that can generate license key for the forged application. You can make this attack difficult by self-verification of your own executable.

However, no security scheme is foolproof, java/android application can be reverse engineered and a determined hacker can forge your application and disable its license checks. The only foolproof way to prevent unauthorized usage of an application is to not distribute the application at all.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you could get 99% of the effect of a more complex scheme with a brain-dead-simple one: just store a file somewhere on the device that indicates that the trial has expired. Granted, tech-savvy users would be able to find and remove the file, but the vast majority won't bother - the device is an inscrutable slab of magic to them, meddling with the internal files might displease the tiny gnomes peddling furiously behind the screen.

You can make things more challenging by hiding the lock file, changing the name and location based on the device id - that way it's a lot more difficult for someone to share instructions on how to evade your trial scheme.

As the other answers have noted: no system is foolproof, there is always someone out there who is cleverer than you and who will relish cracking your scheme. The trick is to not waste your time giving this guy a mental workout and instead cater for the majority.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but you'll need to be set up to store device identifiers on your own server. On an iphone, you can obtain the UDID using

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];
```

You might make a database call and acompare `uniqueIdentifier` to your stored list, ensuring that only one trial can be activated per device.

In android, `getDeviceID()` gives you a unique device identifier. check [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29) for more info on this.

Comment: +1,  but is this really secure?  At the end of the day i have to be sending a request to my server, and whats stopping an attacker from forging a request?

Comment: true; but I don't believe there's any other way, as you can't control distribution of apps (due to the App Store and the Marketplace). This definitely makes it difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: @Rook: you could hash the request with a secret key and verify it on your server.

Comment: @donkim an hmac cannot be used to fill this small part of the problem because any secret distributed with the binary is under the attackers control.

Comment: @Rook: yup, this is true. it's just a matter of making it a bit harder to crack

Comment: @donkim  I'm sorry but that is unacceptable.  Its a matter of it being secure or not even trying.   If that is the case then we cannot provide a trail.

Comment: Fair enough. Different requirements for different projects. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not missing something, my solution would be straightforward. I will make the expire the service provided by the app, not the app itself. This can be done by using some token mechanism like oAuth. (with an expiring token with a considerable lifetime, in this case your trial period). While the client registration process, I will create the request token as a function of android device id and the requested time. Checkout oAuth, it could be a hassle, but almost all major service providers use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the MAC address of wifi adapter? Possibly on you server and you app will query the server if that MAC is already registered.

WITH USER'S PERMISSION, on the first run of app, query the server if current device's MAC address is already registered? If not, store the MAC address on your server. If already registered, ask user to purchase the app in order to continue using.

This method can be supplemented by some cryptographic algorithms as suggested by Lie Ryan to provide additional security and locks and/or trial period.

I don't know much about iPhone but I believe that every iPhone has wifi adapter and every wifi adapter has unique MAC address. Also check the legal side of this solution as storing the MAC may raise privacy issues/concerns. So, before using this, check laws applicable.